# ASP.NET MVC Authorization without SQL Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, authorization

I want to use standard authorization with forms. But all tables must be saved not in mdb file which used by default, but in Oracle. 
Would you please provide me information how to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Oracle providers for ASP.NET.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E15168_01/IntroOverview.htm

Answer (score 2):

I've never had to use Oracle, but to help you out you need to look into the [ASP.NET Membership Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479021.aspx).  By default it does point at SQL Server, but I believe there have been Oracle implementations that are available.